# Get / set a map image mouse location

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image, google-maps

I need to develop asp.net webApplication from scratch without using google map api, that set location on a map image when user selects any location, and set any image map locator on the current location that user has selected it.

More clear, its like google map. I display a map for user and then user selects any location to build his/her house for example, then on mouse leave i set an selector image for that location "like the red arrow on google map", and save the selected image pixels, on Get process of user data i put that image selector on the location user has previously selected.

I need any article that could help me on that and tools that can supports me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming jQuery:

Observe the related mouse-event(e.g. click), it will have the properties `pageX` and `pageY`(the mouse-coordinates relative to the document).

The offset of the "map" you will get via [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

So the click-coordinates(what you have to store) related to the map will be:

```
x: event.pageX-mapOffset.left
y: event.pageY-mapOffset.top
```

To draw the marker(red arrow or something) you must calculate the offset from the click-coordinates(A default-maps-marker is anchored at center/bottom).
Substract the height and the half width of the marker from the click-coordinates to get the correct position.

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jth8fdy4/